# How can I programatically pin an item that displays a jump list to the start menu in WIN7

Tags: windows-7, startmenu, jump-list

I want to add an item to the start menu to display a list of applications that the user can launch. Kind of like a custom menu. I got the WIN API code pack and understand that I can use a jump list for the popup menu part. Not sure how I can pin something to the start menu though. I'm looking for something along the lines of what IE displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to accomplish this using Shell32 library.

```
public static class VerbNames{
    public static string PinToStartMenu = "Pin to Start Men&u";
    public static string UnpinFromStartMenu = "Unpin from Start Men&u";

    public static string PinToTaskbar = "Pin to Tas&kbar";
    public static string UnpinFromTaskbar = "Unpin from Tas&kbar";
}

public static class DesktopUtil {
    public static void PinItemToStartMenu(string itemPath, string itemName) {
        DoItemVerb(itemPath, itemName, VerbNames.PinToStartMenu);
    }

    public static void UnpinItemFromStartMenu(string itemPath, string itemName) {
        DoItemVerb(itemPath, itemName, VerbNames.UnpinFromStartMenu);
    }

    public static void PinItemToTaskbar(string itemPath, string itemName) {
        DoItemVerb(itemPath, itemName, VerbNames.PinToTaskbar);
    }

    public static void UnpinItemFromTaskbar(string itemPath, string itemName) {
        DoItemVerb(itemPath, itemName, VerbNames.UnpinFromTaskbar);
    }

    private static void DoItemVerb(string itemPath, string itemName, string verb) {
        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();

        Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(itemPath);

        Shell32.FolderItem item = folder.ParseName(itemName);

        DoItemVerb(item, verb);
    }

    private static void DoItemVerb(Shell32.FolderItem item, string verbToDo) {
        Shell32.FolderItemVerbs verbs = item.Verbs();

        foreach (Shell32.FolderItemVerb verb in verbs) {
            if (verb.Name.Equals(verbToDo)) {
                verb.DoIt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```